# ImportError : No module named 'werkzeug' while attempting Odoo 10 database migration to Odoo 11

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, database-migration, odoo-10

I am following [this article](https://agipme.fr/2018/10/odoo-10-ce-upgrade-to-version-11.html) to perform my **Odoo 10 database migration** to **Odoo 11** but I got an **ImportError : No module named 'werkzeug'** error.

Is everyone got the same problem? I am open for all suggestions.

I am  using  odoo docker  image  odoo:10  with  postgres:10 on separated containers.

**Thanks for reading**.

Here is more details about  the  issue .

```
odoo@f807a4a071e3:~/OpenUpgrade_11$ cd OpenUpgrade/

odoo@f807a4a071e3:~/OpenUpgrade_11/OpenUpgrade$ ls

CONTRIBUTING.md COPYRIGHT LICENSE MANIFEST.in Makefile README.md addons debian doc odoo odoo-bin requirements.txt scripts setup setup.cfg setup.py

odoo@f807a4a071e3:~/OpenUpgrade_11/OpenUpgrade$ sudo -u odoo ./odoo-bin -d TestDB_Migr --update all --stop-after-init --data-dir=/tmp/

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./odoo-bin", line 5, in 
        import odoo
    File "/var/lib/odoo/OpenUpgrade_11/OpenUpgrade/odoo/__init__.py", line 84, in 
        from . import modules
    File "/var/lib/odoo/OpenUpgrade_11/OpenUpgrade/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in 
        from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
    File "/var/lib/odoo/OpenUpgrade_11/OpenUpgrade/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 10, in     
        import odoo.tools as tools
    File "/var/lib/odoo/OpenUpgrade_11/OpenUpgrade/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 9, in 
        from .misc import *
    File "/var/lib/odoo/OpenUpgrade_11/OpenUpgrade/odoo/tools/misc.py", line 25, in 
        import werkzeug.utils
ImportError: No module named 'werkzeug'

odoo@f807a4a071e3:~/OpenUpgrade_11/OpenUpgrade$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [document](https://agipme.fr/2018/10/odoo-10-ce-upgrade-to-version-11.html) you afforded, it mentioned:

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade.git
>
> - install python requirements
>
> cd OpenUpgrade
>
> git checkout 11.0
>
> sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt
> ```

Have a look at its [requirements.txt](https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade/blob/11.0/requirements.txt#L45), you could see next:

> Werkzeug==0.11.15 ; sys_platform != 'win32'

So, most probably you should execute `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` to install dependent python package before execute other command.

Comment: I followed all those steps but I ignored Exceptions lifted by the **pip3 install Werkzeug==0.11.15**

Comment: **The error due by pip3 install Werkzeug==0.11.15**  
  
`odoo@f807a4a071e3:~/OpenUpgrade_11/OpenUpgrade$ pip3 install Werkzeug==0.11.15  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module> 
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 57   
   sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")  
                                  ^   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax   
odoo@f807a4a071e3:~/OpenUpgrade_11/OpenUpgrade$
`
  
**I apologize for the poor rendering of the error.**

Comment: What's your base image?

Comment: My installation docker-image run on docker **odoo:10**

Comment: It's strange that the error not shown in my part. But from the error you given, looks it related to pip, python3.4 surely not support `f-string`. So could you in a fresh container, not upgrade the pip like `pip3 install --upgrade pip`. If __not__ execute above, will it ok for you?

Comment: I will try without upgrading the pip util. 
But, Odoo:10 container don't came with PIP3.  
You would suggest that I just install PIP3 without upgrading it?

Comment: YES, just try it please.

Comment: I deployed a new container based on the same docker image without upgrading the pip3 util.

I don't have the error again. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP @atline